# How to integrate a bootstrap 4 table with Angular?

Tags: jquery, html, angular, datatables, bootstrap-4

I am tring to intergrate [this bootstrap 4 table](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4) with angular but I am having issues.

It seems as if jquery is not working well. Here is [my working implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugkjaz?file=src%2Findex.html). The problem I have is that every time I make a change on the app component the jquery part of the form stops working. Also see the index file... I had to put the 'document ready' script there for the table to work. How can I stop  the jquery part of the form from stopping to work with every change I make?

Is there a better bootstrap 4 table that will easily integrate with angular that has the sorting, filter and pagination features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using jQuery with Angular. You will fall into a lot of trouble with that.

Have you tried looking at Angulars implementation of Bootstrap, for example: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home ?

Comment: What about the j query that comes with bootstrap in angular.... is that okay?

Comment: The Angulars implementation of Bootstrap is what I needed thanks

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't use jQuery. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started
"This repository contains a set of native Angular directives based on Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript is required."

Comment: That I have seen... I as asking about the normal bootstrap that has popper.js and jquery as dependencies... is that advised against?

Comment: Well, you can do that, but the main issues is that Angular is not working with DOM directly and jQuery is. That results in multiple bottlenecks, for example, you have to control that your content is rendered before accessing it.

Comment: Ah, I see... I now understand. Seems I'll have to start designing my front end with ng-bootstrap. Trying to use j query has really consumed my time. Thank you.